# Safari ignoring input checkbox positioning and width/height as well as slightly moving once checked

Tags: html, css, safari

I been looking for this problem over the internet but I cant seem to find one that fix all of if, I have a parent div that centers all elements, but would not center the check box (only in safari) I tried moving it about using different methods such as margin, left/right etc etc, but nothing makes that little bastard move from its original place. Neither does the width/height works.

```
.right-content{
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 300px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-color: #DC0000;
    text-align: center;
}

.right-content a {
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

<div id="sidebarMort" class="right-content">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeSIdeBar()">&times;</a>
    <a style="margin-top: 50px"><h2>Mortgage Calculator</h2></a>
    <a><input name="income" type="text" id="income" placeholder="Annual Income"></a><br>
    <p>Are you First Time Buyer?</p><br>
    <a>Yes<input type="checkbox" id="ftb" value="ftb"></a><br>
    <a><p>No</p><input type="checkbox" id="stb" value="stb"></a>
    <a><input type="submit" class="btnOnBar" value="Calculate"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Luke i don't think that there is need to put `Input` inside anchor tag. Please update your code first. here is the updated code please check. Ypu can use `label` instead of `anchor tag` . Rest you can update visual as per your requirement using css.

```html
<div id="sidebarMort" class="right-content">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeSIdeBar()">&times;</a>
    <a style="margin-top: 50px"><h2>Mortgage Calculator</h2></a>
    <a><input name="income" type="text" id="income" placeholder="Annual Income"></a><br>
    <p>Are you First Time Buyer?</p><br>
    <label for="ftb">Yes<input type="checkbox" id="ftb" value="ftb"></label>
    <label for="stb">No<input type="checkbox" id="stb" value="stb"></label>
    <input type="submit" class="btnOnBar" value="Calculate">
</div>
```